# Can a Jewish Woman marry a Non Jewish Man?

Tags: marriage

I heard a Jewish woman can marry a non-Jewish man because Jewishness is through the mother and not the father.

Are there any sources saying it's allowed?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Any reputable source or just hear-say?

Comment: It was just hear-say

Answer (score 1):

1. **Having a long-term relationship (marriage) with gentiles is a clear prohibition for both men and women**. It is openly written in [Dvorim 7, 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0507.htm) - "**neither shalt thou make marriages with them: thy daughter thou shalt not give unto his son, nor his daughter shalt thou take unto thy son**."
2. Having relations with a gentile does not count as a marriage in Judaism, and a Jewish woman that had a secular marriage with a gentile can marry a Jew right away with no divorce. She can only be "officially registered" as such.
3. It is true, that this kind of relations is less severe than a Jewish man with a gentile woman. Also kids from this relations stay rightful Jews.

Comment: But we probably hold 1 is only talking want l about the seven nations; not every gentile. Number 2 is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It is clear to me that the questioner seeks for a clear and sound answer, not for the Halakhic Makhlokoys.

Comment: Your answer is basically מגלה פנים בתורה שלא כהלכה. It is clear to me that the OP wants the truth. Not lies. It is a lie (of omission, if not of commission) to state that Judaism interprets that verse as biblically prohibiting intermarriage to gentiles.

Comment: Now you just added an unsourced (likely incorrect (as it could be argued that it is worse to bring Jews into the world who will not be raised observant, or even necessarily Jewish, that non-Jews) claim) to a lie, and an another unsourced claim. || This post just keeps getting worse. Please correct its problems or delete it.

Comment: @mevaqesh Kiddushin 68b supports you. Only R’ Shimon holds of this source for the other nations; the Chachamim derive it from Yefas To’ar.

Comment: Rambam was megaleh panim shelo kehalachah? ישראל שבעל גויה משאר האומות, דרך אישות, או ישראלית שנבעלה לגוי, דרך אישות--הרי אלו לוקין מן התורה, שנאמר "לא תתחתן, בם" (דברים ז,ג): אחד שבעה עממין, ואחד כל האומות באיסור זה. וכן מפורש על ידי עזרא "ואשר לא ניתן בנותינו, לעמי הארץ; ואת בנותיהם, לא ניקח לבנינו" (נחמיה י,לא). ולא אסרה תורה, אלא דרך חתנות

Comment: The unsourced claim can likely be sourced in the ramban (milchamot to Sanhedrin dad 74)